# Bayesian nonlinear regression with PyMC3

Tags: bayesian, pymc3, non-linear-regression

First time PyMC3 user here trying to use the module for Bayesian Nonlinear Regression. Given input-output data (x_i, y_i), the modelling assumption is

[image]

where the function f is *nonlinear* in the model parameters *w*. Consequently,

[image].

Assume for simplicity that 
[image] and that all samples are independently sampled such that the joint likelihood is equal to the product of the individual likelihoods.

**Goal**: Compute posterior probability for model parameters *w*.

In a first step, I need to define the function that for each x_i gives me the expected value.

```
@as_op(itypes=[tt.dscalar]*5, otypes=[tt.dvector])
def compute_expected_value(eta, rho, lamd, vbar, v0):

    model_param = [[eta, rho, lamd, vbar, v0]]

    # Expected value of outcome
    model_param = np.tile(model_param, (len(df), 1))
    features = np.column_stack((model_param, df.maturity, df.strike))  
    features = standardise_inputs(features, train_mean, train_std)
    exp_value, _ = predict(features, nn, sess)

    return exp_value.reshape(-1)
```

Given a dataframe with data and model parameters w=(eta, rho, lambda, vbar, v0), inputs are standardised and then fed into a neural network coded using Tensorflow (this is abstracted away in the `predict` function). I then try to follow as closely as possible the *Linear* regression  [tutorial](https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/getting_started.html#A-Motivating-Example:-Linear-Regression).

```
def build_model():

    with basic_model as model:

        # Uniform priors for unknown model parameters
        eta = pm.Uniform('eta', lower=0, upper=5)
        rho = pm.Uniform('rho', lower=-1, upper=0)
        lamd = pm.Uniform('lambda',lower=0, upper=10)
        vbar = pm.Uniform('vbar', lower=0, upper=1)
        v0 = pm.Uniform('v0', lower=0, upper=1)

        sigma = pm.HalfNormal('sigma', sd=1)

        # Returns a (1337,) numpy vector for the expected value
        print('Compute NN IV.')
        mean = compute_expected_value(eta, rho, lamd, vbar, v0)
        print('NN IV computed.')

        # Likelihood (sampling distribution) of observations
        Y_obs = pm.Normal('Y_obs', mu=mean, sd=sigma, observed=df.iv.values)

    return model

def run(n=500):
    model = build_model()
    with model:
        db = pm.backends.Text('test')
        trace = pm.sample(n, step=pm.Metropolis(), trace=db)

    pm.traceplot(trace)
```

As pointed out by @merv, NUTS is not available because the package can't get the gradient from my neural network Tensorflow implementation, so I try to use Metropolis. This however returns:

```
Compute NN IV.
NN IV computed.
Multiprocess sampling (2 chains in 2 jobs)
CompoundStep
>Metropolis: [sigma]
>Metropolis: [v0]
>Metropolis: [vbar]
>Metropolis: [lambda]
>Metropolis: [rho]
>Metropolis: [eta]
Sampling 2 chains:   0%|          | 0/2000 [00:00<?, ?draws/s]
```

So obviously the test run works (as seen by the print statements) but the simulation of the Markov Chain does not.

1. Why does the MCMC not run?
2. As in the  [tutorial](https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/getting_started.html#A-Motivating-Example:-Linear-Regression), I pass an array and not a scalar for *mu*, is this correct?

Comment: Could you provide a reduced example (including simulation data) that still replicates the error? As it stands, others cannot test the example.  Also, please link to the "official regression example" that you referenced in the code comments.

Comment: Without having a simpler example, I will suggest switching to Metropolis sampling (`pm.sample(..., step=pm.Metropolis())`). PyMC3 is failing to compute a gradient (which is needed for NUTS), and this is likely due to what appears to be an MLE step (`compute_exp_value `) to estimate the `y^hat_i = f(x_i, w)` values in the middle of the sampling.  Since that is effectively a black box, theano can't differentiate the computation graph and so NUTS initialization fails.  The other option is to be explicit about how the `f` values are computed.

Comment: @merv, thank you for your valuable feedback. I have clarified the question and added some more info since reducing it to MWE is not feasible. You are right in assuming that the function that computes the expected value is a blackbox (a Tensorflow NN), so Tensorflow gradients are available but theano cannot access Tensorflows computation graph. I tried Metropolis but as described above the chain does not run.